# How can I send a form without the image (filename)

Tags: node.js, filenames

I test a post with filename but in postman if I don't add image then I have an image undefine, that is ok. But I can't send it if the image don't pass as null.

Here is my controller with filename

```html
module.exports.createComment  = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.body.message) {
      res.status(400).send({
        message: "Content can not be empty!"
      });
    }
    let { id, message, date, image} = req.body;
    image = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/images/${req.file.filename}`,
    Comment.create({
      id, message, date, image
    }).then((comment) => res.status(201).send(comment))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.send(`Error: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

My response without image on Postman : Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `req.file` because access `filename`. Because when you don't pass it, `req.file` will be `undefined` which cannot access `filename`

```
let { id, message, date, image } = req.body;
if (req.file) {
    image = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/images/${req.file.filename}`
} else {
    image = null;
}
```